# How to define a b-open set relative to a larger set?

Tags: general-topology, definition

In the paper of D. Andrijevic entitled "On b-open Sets", it is defined that

> A subset $S$ of a topological space $(X,\tau)$ is $b$-open if
>
> $$ S\subseteq\bar{\operatorname{int} S}\cup \operatorname{int}\bar{S}$$

Now, if $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$, how to define the concept of "$A$ is $b$-open relative to $B$"?

Comment: Where have you encountered this notion of "b-open set relative to $Y$"? Your question is lacking context!

Comment: sorry for that, I am new to this site. I am recently studying the paper of Andrijevic entitled "On b-open Sets". I want to extend his paper relating to relative topology but I can't seem to find the definition of b-open set relative to A. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is b-open if it is in the topology on $Y$ and $S\subset\overline{\mathrm{int}(S)}\cup \mathrm{int}(\overline{S})$

Where in general  $\rm int$, is the interior of a set which is the union of all **open** sets contained in the set.

Comment: suppose X is a subspace of Y, how would you define b-open set in X?

Comment: @Xrylche Perhaps the most natural definition would be that a subset $S\subset X\subset Y$ (where $Y$ is a topological space) is relatively b-open in $X$ if it is b-open a subset of $X$ equipped with the induced topology from $Y$.

Comment: well I Think you would either endow $X$ with the subspace topology, in which case, $S\subset X$ would be b-open with respect to $X$ if it is in the topology defined on $X$ and $S\subset \overline{int(S)}\cup int(\overline{S})$

Comment: Or if not, if $S\subset X\subset Y$ and $S$ is in the topology on $Y$ and $S\subset\overline{int(S)}\cup int(\overline{S})$ then $S$ would be b-open relative to $Y$

Comment: @OlivierBégassat do you mean I could write S as S \subseteq cl_A (int_A (S)) \cup int_A (cl_A (S))? Sorry for the notation. I am a newbe in this site, I am using latex format in typing my equation.

Comment: Yes that is exactly right and to typeset correctly put a dollar sign on both sides of the whole of your formatted latex.